# mysql random least used

Tags: mysql

I need to select a record at random but not one already selected before unless all records have been selected.

Table Setup:
_word (id, nam)
_word_tm (id, word_id, tm)

Every time a word is used it is loaded into _word_tm. What I am wanting to do is make sure I use all the words before I reuse an already used word.

What I am really looking for is something like the below but just trying to figure out how to mesh.

select w.nam FROM _word w LEFT JOIN _word_tm wt ON w.id = wt.word_id ORDER BY count(wt.id) asc, rand() limit 1

Comment: Do you have a constraint to do all this at the database level via a SQL statement or are you open to doing it in mid-tier as well?

Comment: No constraint. I use php/mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find out how many times the least-used words have been used:

```
select _word.id, count(*) c from _word
left join _word_tm on _word.id=_word_tm.word_id order by c limit 1;
```

Store that value (from c) in a variable `$least_used`. Then get all the words used that many times, in random order:

```
select _word.id, count(*) c from _word
left join _word_tm on _word.id=_word_tm.word_id
group by _word.id having c <= {$least_used}
order by rand() limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM word_table WHERE word NOT IN (SELECT word FROM words_used) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;
```

You will need to have an updated copy of MySQL for this to work.  Also, you would need to include a line of code afterward or before hand to clear/reset your `words_used` table once it had the same contents as `word_table`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following SQL to return a random row

```
select A.nam
from _word A
where A.id not in (select B.id from _word_tm B)
order by rand()
limit 1
```

if the above does not return any reocrd , do a simple

```
select A.nam
from _word A
order by rand()
limit 1
```